# How to set tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint without explicit model.fit?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to add `Checkpoint` during the tranning process in a code. I know the way by setting `callbacks = callbacks` in `model.fit`. However, in the code, there is no explicit calling of `model.fit` insead through `K.function` as follows. Could anyone tell me where is the right location to set checkpoint? The full code can be viewed through [this github link](https://github.com/zhang-rite/tf_learning/blob/main/train.py).

```py
vae_model = vae_util.create_vae(input_shape)
vae_model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse')
rec_loss = vae_loss(vae_model.output, train_target)
total_loss = rec_loss
updates = opt.get_updates(total_loss, vae_model.trainable_weights)

iterate = K.function(vae_model.inputs + [train_target], [rec_loss], updates=updates)

eval_rec_loss = vae_loss(vae_model.output, test_target)
evaluate = K.function(vae_model.inputs + [test_target], [eval_rec_loss])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code already has safepoint saving in [line 139](https://github.com/zhang-rite/tf_learning/blob/main/train.py#L149)